# `$$` working in mozilla but not working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm using the Prototype framework the following code to get the length of the checked check box length which is working in Mozilla , but not working in IE 7 ?

```
questionIdArray[i] = 5;
id="choiceCheckBox-"+questionIdArray[i];
length = $$('input[name='+id+']:checked').length;
```

Comment: When you say it isn't working, do you mean it isn't returning the correct length, or that it is causing a javascript error?  I ran the code above (changing questionIdArray[i] to 'q' and it worked fine.

Comment: @ChiperSoft : Its not returning a value, in IE only this problem , length value is not reurning and execution stops der .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not seeing all of your code it's hard to say if this is the problem, but based on what you've posted my first guess is that you aren't initializing `length` as a local variable, so your code is actually applying the value to `window.length`, which appears to be a protected variable in IE7.

Add `var` in front of your assignment.